# SQLITE database error "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: table"

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am confused...
I have a file "calculation.py" which contains which contains following code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('matchprediction.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT * FROM spielplan WHERE table = 8")
```

In addition I run that file via the local host in django to simulate a webserver.

**Whenever I start the server with python manage.py runserver, I get the error message:**

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: table
```

The database definitely exists and the table itself, too. Have checked it with a DB Browser.
The calculations.py works, because it retrieves data from this table to execute the calculation. The output result in the run-window is correct.

What am I doing wrong and how may I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure it's opening the _right_ `matchprediction.db`? Since you're not using an absolute path, it's relative to the working directory of the server, which could be anything.

Comment: Well, I have two matchprediction.db. One in the project folder (empty) and one in the app folder (contains table and its content). I guess it's the right matchprediction.db, cuz otherwise the calculation in the script would not work. If I hover over the matchprediction.py, copy the path, browse to that path and open that specific matchprediction.py it contains the table 'spielplan' and all data I need.

Comment: It appears that your table `spielplan` has a column named `table`. But in most dialects of SQL, `table` is a reserved word (as in `create table`).

Answer (score 0):

> Well, I have two matchprediction.db. One in the project folder (empty) and one in the app folder (contains table and its content).

The empty one in the project folder was created by the Django server being run with the project folder as the working directory and you calling `sqlite3.connect()` with a relative path.

If you run (or have run) `app/calculation.py` on the command line, the working directory for that script will be `app/`.

If you want to make this more bullet-proof, you can form the true path to the database with

```
import os

database_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'matchprediction.db')

conn = sqlite3.connect(database_path)
```

– i.e. always anchor `matchprediction.db` to the module path that has that `database_path =` line instead of the working directory.

Comment: That works for me. Thank you soooo much! unfortunately can't upvote you yet. But will consider you in my bedtime prays :P